# I have an old dataflow template and we update our databse security and now I need to stage and extra file to make it work

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I ​​​​​​​have an issue and this is killing me, I am writing this to find a solution.

In my old architecture, everything was working fine:

- we have some data in a JDBC that is accessible from a specific subnet
- we extract data with cloud functions and write them in BigQuery

My new setup:

- same database but with extra security and I have to use a certificate to connect
- I have added some parameters to my connections string useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true&serverTimezone=UTC&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/extra_files/ca-root.pem
- the same setup for the rest of the function

The error I get and I just can’t get around it: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Cannot open file:/extra_files/ca-root.pem [/extra_files/ca-root.pem (No such file or directory)]

From this https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/ssl-certificates it is that simple but my setup is just a little more complicate

I have added the template parameter and the job is still not working, the file is just not there, I am missing something I don't know what.

My working setup:
Dataflow - MySQLToBigQuery.java:

```
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowJsonCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

/**
 * MySQL to BigQuery pipeline.
 */
public class MySQLToBigQuery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create pipeline
        CustomPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
                .as(CustomPipelineOptions.class);

        run(options);
    }

    /**
     * Runs the pipeline with the supplied options.
     *
     * @param options The execution parameters to the pipeline.
     * @return PipelineResult
     */
    private static PipelineResult run(CustomPipelineOptions options) {
        // Create the pipeline
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        /*
         * Steps: 1) Read records via JDBC and convert to TableRow via RowMapper
         *        2) Append TableRow to BigQuery via BigQueryIO
         */
        pipeline
                /*
                 * Step 1: Read records via JDBC and convert to TableRow
                 *         via {@link org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO.RowMapper}
                 */
                .apply(
                        "Read from MySQL",
                        JdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
                                .withDataSourceConfiguration(
                                        JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                                                StaticValueProvider.of("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"), options.getConnectionURL())
                                                .withUsername(options.getUsername())
                                                .withPassword(options.getPassword())
                                                .withConnectionProperties(options.getConnectionProperties()))
                                .withQuery(options.getQuery())
                                .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
                                .withRowMapper(getResultSetToTableRow()))

                /*
                 * Step 2: Append TableRow to an existing BigQuery table
                 */
                .apply(
                        "Write to BigQuery",
                        BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                                .withoutValidation()
                                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                                .withCustomGcsTempLocation(options.getBigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory())
                                .to(options.getOutputTable()));

        // Execute the pipeline.
        return pipeline.run();
    }

    /**
     * Factory method for {@link ResultSetToTableRow}.
     */
    private static JdbcIO.RowMapper<TableRow> getResultSetToTableRow() {
        return new ResultSetToTableRow();
    }
/**
 * {@link JdbcIO.RowMapper} implementation to convert Jdbc ResultSet rows to UTF-8 encoded JSONs.
 */
private static class ResultSetToTableRow implements JdbcIO.RowMapper<TableRow> {

    @Override
    public TableRow mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

        TableRow outputTableRow = new TableRow();

        for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            outputTableRow.set(metaData.getColumnName(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
        }

        return outputTableRow;
    }
}
```

}

Dataflow: CustomPipelineOptions.java

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;

public interface CustomPipelineOptions extends PipelineOptions {
    @Description(
            "The JDBC connection URL string. " + "for example: jdbc:mysql://some-host:3306/sampledb")
    ValueProvider<String> getConnectionURL();

    void setConnectionURL(ValueProvider<String> connectionURL);

    @Description(
            "JDBC connection property string. " + "for example: unicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8")
    ValueProvider<String> getConnectionProperties();

    void setConnectionProperties(ValueProvider<String> connectionProperties);

    @Description("JDBC connection user name. ")
    ValueProvider<String> getUsername();

    void setUsername(ValueProvider<String> username);

    @Description("JDBC connection password. ")
    ValueProvider<String> getPassword();

    void setPassword(ValueProvider<String> password);

    @Description("Source data query string. " + "for example: select * from sampledb.sample_table")
    ValueProvider<String> getQuery();

    void setQuery(ValueProvider<String> query);

    @Description(
            "BigQuery Table spec to write the output to"
                    + "for example: some-project-id:somedataset.sometable")
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputTable();

    void setOutputTable(ValueProvider<String> outputTable);

    @Description("Temporary directory for BigQuery loading process")
    ValueProvider<String> getBigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory();

    void setBigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory(ValueProvider<String> bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory);
}
```

My index.js for cloud function:

```
/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload.
 * @param {!Object} context Metadata for the event.
 */
exports.startDataflow = async (event, context) => {
    // general constants
    const REGION = process.env.REGION;
    const ZONE = process.env.ZONE;
    const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET;
    const SUBNET = process.env.SUBNET;
    const NETWORK = process.env.NETWORK
    const TOPIC_MONITOR = process.env.TOPIC_MONITOR;

    // MySQL config
    const mySqlConfig = {
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
        port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
        username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
        properties: process.env.MYSQL_PROPERTIES,
        timezone: process.env.MYSQL_TIMEZONE
    };
    
    // import modules
    const DataflowUtil = require('./dataflow-util');
    const dataflowUtil = new DataflowUtil();

    const BqUtil = require('./bq-util.js');
    const bqUtil = new BqUtil();

    const QueryUtil = require('./query-util');
    const queryUtil = new QueryUtil(BUCKET);


    const SchedulerUtil = require('./scheduler-util');
    const schedulerUtil = new SchedulerUtil();

    const userData = Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString();
    console.log(`Input data received: ${userData}`);

    const inputData = JSON.parse(userData);

    async function main() {
        // find Project ID
        console.log('Finding current project ID.');
        const projectId = await dataflowUtil.getProjectId();
        
        // create Big Query staging and destination table
        let stagingTableExists = await bqUtil.tableExists(inputData.stagingTable);
        if (stagingTableExists) {
            console.log('Deleting Big Query staging table.');
            await bqUtil.deleteTable(inputData.stagingTable);
            stagingTableExists = false;
        }

        const destinationTableExists = await bqUtil.tableExists(inputData.destinationTable);
        if (!stagingTableExists || !destinationTableExists) {
            // extract schema from MySQL
            if (typeof inputData.schema !== "undefined") {
                console.log('Extracting Big Query schema from input data.');
                var fields = inputData.schema;
            } else {
                console.log('Extracting Big Query schema from MySQL.');
                const fields = await bqUtil.extractFieldsFromMySql(inputData.columns, inputData.sourceTable, mySqlConfig);
            }

            if (!stagingTableExists) {
                console.log('Creating Big Query staging table.');
                await bqUtil.createTable(inputData.stagingTable, fields);
            }
   
            if (!destinationTableExists) {
                console.log('Creating Big Query destination table.');
                await bqUtil.createTable(inputData.destinationTable, fields);
            }
        }

        // assemble source MySQL query
        const queryFields = inputData.columns.join("`, `");
        let query = `SELECT \`${queryFields}\` FROM \`${inputData.sourceTable}\``;
        
        // get the latest offset in order to compose the query
        if (typeof inputData.limitColumn !== 'undefined' && inputData.limitColumn.length > 0) {
            console.log('Reading current offset from Cloud Storage.');
            var limitStart = await queryUtil.lastOffset(inputData.jobName, inputData.limitColumn, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
            var limitEnd = queryUtil.flexibleUTC(-5);
            var extendedLimitEnd = queryUtil.flexibleUTC(+5);;
            query += ` WHERE \`${inputData.limitColumn}\` >= '${limitStart}' AND \`${inputData.limitColumn}\` <= '${extendedLimitEnd}'`;
        }
        console.log(`MySQL query: ${query}`);

        // run dataflow job
        console.log('Starting Dataflow job from template.');
        const dataflowConfig = {
            projectId: projectId,
            region: REGION,
            jobName: inputData.jobName,
            templatePath: `gs://${BUCKET}/templates/MySQLToBigQuery`,
            connection: mySqlConfig,
            query: query,
            outputTable: inputData.stagingTable,
            bqLoadTempLocation: `gs://${BUCKET}/bq-temp`,
            tempLocation: `gs://${BUCKET}/temp`,
            network: NETWORK,
            subnetwork: SUBNET,
            zone: ZONE,
            machineType: inputData.machineType || 'n1-standard-1',
        };
        await dataflowUtil.startJobFromTemplate(dataflowConfig).then((dataflowJobId) => {
            // setup Cloud Scheduler monitoring cron
            console.log('Setting up Cloud Scheduler cron for monitoring Dataflow job.');
            inputData.dataflowJobId = dataflowJobId; // pass the Dataflow job ID to the monitoring function
            const config = {
                projectId: projectId,
                region: REGION,
                jobName: `monitor-dataflow-${dataflowJobId}`,
                description: 'Triggers a Cloud Function for monitoring a Dataflow job.',
                topic: TOPIC_MONITOR,
                payload: inputData,
                schedule: '* * * * *',
                timezone: "UTC"
            };
            
            return schedulerUtil.createJob(config);
        }).then((data)=>{
            // save new offset
            if (typeof limitEnd !== "undefined" && typeof limitStart !== "undefined") {
                console.log('Saving new offset in Cloud Storage.');
                return queryUtil.saveOffset(inputData.jobName, inputData.limitColumn, limitEnd, limitStart);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log('Done starting dataflow job.');
        });
    }

    await main();
};

/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload.
 * @param {!Object} context Metadata for the event.
 */
exports.monitorDataflow = async (event, context) => {

    // general constants
    const REGION = process.env.REGION;
    const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET;

    // import modules
    const DataflowUtil = require('./dataflow-util');
    const dataflowUtil = new DataflowUtil();

    const SchedulerUtil = require('./scheduler-util');
    const schedulerUtil = new SchedulerUtil();

    const BqUtil = require('./bq-util');
    const bqUtil = new BqUtil();

    const QueryUtil = require('./query-util');
    const queryUtil = new QueryUtil(BUCKET);

    const userData = Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString();
    console.log(`Input data received: ${userData}`);

    const inputData = JSON.parse(userData);

    /**
     * Returns the MERGE query
     * 
     * @param {string} stagingTable 
     * @param {string} destinationTable 
     * @param {string} columns 
     * @param {string} pkColumn 
     */
    function assembleMergeQuery(stagingTable, destinationTable, columns, pkColumn) {

        let updateStatement = [];
        columns.forEach(element => {
            updateStatement.push(`D.\`${element}\` = S.\`${element}\``);
        });
    
        const query = `MERGE \`${destinationTable.replace(':', '.')}\` D
            USING \`${stagingTable.replace(':', '.')}\` S ON S.\`${pkColumn}\` = D.\`${pkColumn}\`
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT (\`${columns.join("`, `")}\`) VALUES (\`${columns.join("`, `")}\`)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE SET ${updateStatement.join(", ")}`;
    
        return query;
    }

    async function main() {
        const projectId = await dataflowUtil.getProjectId();

        const status = await dataflowUtil.getJobStatus(projectId, REGION, inputData.dataflowJobId);
        if (status === 'JOB_STATE_DONE') {
            console.log('Deleting Cloud Scheduler job.');
            await schedulerUtil.deleteJob(inputData.csJobName);
           
            console.log('Running Big Query MERGE query.');
            const query = assembleMergeQuery(inputData.stagingTable, inputData.destinationTable, inputData.columns, inputData.pkColumn);
            let queryJobId = await bqUtil.runQuery(query, projectId);
            console.log(`Big Query query ${queryJobId} has been started. Done.`);
        } else if(status === 'JOB_STATE_FAILED' || status === 'JOB_STATE_CANCELLED'){
            console.log(`Deleting Cloud Scheduler job for failed/canceled dataflow job (${status}).`);
            await schedulerUtil.deleteJob(inputData.csJobName);
            
            console.log('Rolling back offset.');
            await queryUtil.rollbackOffset(inputData.jobName, inputData.limitColumn);
            console.log('Done.');
        } else {
            console.log('Job is still in progress (' + status + '). Exiting.');
        }
    }

    await main();
};
```

Comment: You mention `but my setup is just a little more complicated`. What is your setup? Are you using the `extraFilesToStage template parameter`? Edit your post with more details.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you for your question. I have edited the post and added my files.

Comment: The file `/extra_files/ca-root.pem` is missing. I do not see anything in your post that shows how you are including that file. Please reread my first comment. Also, what is complicated about your setup? Add more explanation to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process described in https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/ssl-certificates works for only [Google-provided templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#streaming-templates).

Are you using the google-provided [MySql to BigQuery template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/mysql-to-bigquery)? If yes, this should work. To double check you can also check the worker logs in Dataflow console. There should be a log saying that the file was staged.

If you are using your own custom template, you will have to implement a JvmInitializer like [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v2/common/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/common/CommonTemplateJvmInitializer.java#L44) and make sure it is in the classpath. In the `beforeProcessing` method of the JvmInitializer you can copy the certificate from GCS and save it locally. [JvmInitializer](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.49.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/harness/JvmInitializer.html) is executed in each worker before data processing begins. Hence, it should make sure that the certificate exists in the worker before the connection to the database is created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I am using a custom template and seems like I should be using JvmInitializer.

I have added the files for JvmInitializer but I don't know how to make sure that the process is going through there. I am new to Java

Comment: You can add log statements inside the `beforeProcessing` method. There should also be worker logs in the dataflow console specifying that JvmInitializer#beforeProcessing method was executed.